# Navigating Back with the keyboard in a Windows 8 Modern UI app

Tags: windows-8-preview

How do you navigate Back with the keyboard in a Windows 8 Modern UI app?

Comment: What metro app are you trying?

Comment: i think it's app-dependent... sometimes ESC works, sometimes it's backspace...

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and it should function as the back key like in Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Tested and this works. +1

Comment: I like backspace - works for me too.

Comment: Does not work on Mail nor Calendar.  This seems to be driven by the application

Answer (score 2):

Hit escape - this should throw you back to the last screen you were on

Comment: that's what i figured too, but it wasn't working

Comment: it only goes as far back as the application home screen rather than the Metro desktop.  But it is better than nothing.

Comment: Question didn't say how far back